# Postgresql count performance

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a count query on a postgresql table. Table name is simcards containing fields id, card_state and 10 more. Simcards contains around 13 million records

My query is

```
SELECT CAST(count(*) AS INT) FROM simcards WHERE card_state = 'ACTIVATED';
```

This is taking more than 6 seconds and I want to optimize it. I tried creating partial index below

```
CREATE INDEX activated_count on simcards (card_state) where card_state = 'ACTIVATED';
```

But no improvements. I think it is because I got more than 12 million records with card_state = 'ACTIVATED'. Note that card_state can be 'ACTIVATED', 'PREPROVISIONED', 'TERMINATED'

Anyone got an idea on how the count can be drastically improved?

Running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT CAST(count(*) AS INT) FROM simcards WHERE card_state = 'ACTIVATED';` gives

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=540300.95..540300.96 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=7103.814..7103.814 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2295 read=155298
  ->  Gather  (cost=540300.74..540300.95 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=7103.773..7103.810 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=2295 read=155298
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=539300.74..539300.75 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7006.368..7006.368 rows=1 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=5983 read=455025
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on simcards  (cost=0.00..526282.77 rows=5207186 width=0) (actual time=2.677..6483.503 rows=4166620 loops=3)
                    Filter: (card_state = 'ACTIVATED'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 10965
                    Buffers: shared hit=5983 read=455025
Planning time: 0.333 ms
Execution time: 7123.739 ms
```

Comment: Please also add the `explain analyze` of your query

Comment: Postgresql will always do seq scan with count. This doesn't scale well with number of rows. One way to get it faster is to have a separate table with count and to put appropriate triggers on the original table. This will dramatically improve read speed at the cost of write speed (which might not be noticable).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name most likely index scan will still be slower than separate table unless there's only 1 or so element in the index.

Comment: If there are many rows with one value creating an index may not help because the planner will perform a full scan anyway.

Comment: @freakish: if the WHERE condition is selective enough the index scan will be more efficient and it **will** be used. Typically if the condition results in less then (roughly!) 20% of the total number of rows, the index scan will be faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name which is false: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#reference Scanning index is stil *scanning*. The percentage of rows is irrelevant. Only the total size of the index matters.

Comment: @kevin: you can try `CREATE INDEX activated_count on simcards (id) where card_state = 'ACTIVATED';` (with `id` being the PK column of the table) - then you might get an index only scan

Comment: @freakish: but an index scan might be more efficient than a seq scan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry that does not work

Comment: @KevinJoymungol: did you run `vacuum analyze simcards` after creating the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are genius. A VACUUM ANALYZE together with the index CREATE INDEX activated_count on simcards (id) where card_state = 'ACTIVATED' did improve the performance many folds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting is slow. Here are a few ideas how to improve it:

1. If you don't need exact results, use PostgreSQL's estimates:

   ```
   /* this will improve the results */
   ANALYZE simcards;

   SELECT t.reltuples * freqs.freq AS count
   FROM pg_class AS t
      JOIN pg_stats AS s
         ON t.relname = s.tablename
            AND t.relnamespace::regnamespace::name = s.schemaname
      CROSS JOIN
         (LATERAL unnest(s.most_common_vals::text::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS vals(val,ord)
          JOIN
          LATERAL unnest(s.most_common_freqs::text::float8[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS freqs(freq,ord)
             USING (ord)
         )
   WHERE s.tablename = 'simcards'
     AND s.attname = 'card_state'
     AND vals.val = 'ACTIVATED';
   ```
2. If you need exact counts, create an extra “counter table” and triggers on `simcards` that update the counter whenever rows are added, removed or modified.

For a more detailed discussion, read [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/).

Comment: Correct. I did a VACUUM ANALYZE together with 
CREATE INDEX activated_count on simcards (id) where card_state = 'ACTIVATED';
This improved things. Thanks for the counter table solution. Will consider it in case I need better performance

Answer (score 0):

Do you test setting the max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4; parameter?

Is probable that some extra worker help here

Regards